# Android application autorotates to landscape mode for a few seconds even when portrait mode is locked

Tags: android, rotation, landscape

I don't know if any of you have seen this before:

I have an application which has the **Portrait orientation locked** for every activity. However, in the HTC Pro Touch phone (and maybe this happens on other phones with physical keyboards) the application rotates to landscape mode for a few seconds and then returns to portait mode, that happens while navigating on the app. Of course this shouldn't happen but I'm not sure why it does that.

I am locking the portrait mode by calling **setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)** in the create method of my super class.

While I was writting this I realized that the locking instruction is called after the super.create(..), could that make a difference? (Testing takes some time if not I would know right now). If not what else could I do to avoid this auto-rotation?

Thanks in advance, I hope someone knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the attribute in your manifest.

```
<activity android:name="bla.blah.bla" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Unless you want to change the orientation later. But that is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will test with that. Basically i didn't do that because there are 30 activities, and it's easier to do it programmatically on the super class  than to copy the manifest property on every activity

Comment: understood! yeah I understand your pain. I had to do it too for around 15 activities. As far as I like android. There's a lot of annoying things like that.